# php variable changes

Tags: php, variables

FIXED!

---

I have 2 php pages that both define the variable "title" as something different. However, echoing the variable on both pages results in the first page's variable's value being displayed on both pages. Any idea why and how I could get the variable to change for each page?

first php page:

```
<?php
    $title = "Posts";
    echo $title;
 ?>
```

This displays "Posts".

second php page:

```
<?php 
  $title = "New Posts";
  echo $title; 
?>
```

This also for some reason displays "Posts". Shouldn't this page display "New Posts"?

Comment: Please show your code, this is not really answerable as-is.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Are you `include`ing one page on the other, or...?

Comment: Do you have [register_globals][1] turned on?

What version of PHP are you using?


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: just added code examples

Comment: PHP 5.3.5 with register_globals off (Ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: Current code examples couldn't work; missing semicolons after variable assignments :]

Comment: Yeah.. fix the code first.. You never know.

Comment: @codedude You're still not showing how the two pages are related. One of these pages must include or otherwise pass control to the other. Can you show us that code? (Also, as said above - the code you've posted is invalid, please post the actual code rather than a simplified example).

Comment: That's the thing. They're not related at all. I can't figure out why the heck its happening.

Comment: I just reproduced that here on my machine and it works fine. I'm running xampp on windows. Are you opening both on the same browser but on different tabs or different browsers altogether?

Comment: Ack...never mind. I figured it out. I had an if statement that was mistyped and causing the error. Thanks for the help anyways. :D

Comment: O.... There was more to the code then.. If you'd showed everything maybe we could've helped u spot it earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are including the second page on the first page *before* you define `$title` on the first page, then the included value will be overwritten.

Are all of your variables defined in the global namespace? If so, this problem will be inevitable when you're including PHP files within other PHP files.

You could resolve the problem by properly encapsulating your variables within a class or namespace; for example:

In file one:

```
<?php
namespace included;
$title = "original title!";
?>
```

And in file two:

```
<?php
namespace including;
require_once "file_one.php";
$title = "new title!";

echo \included\$title;
echo \including\$title;
echo $title;
?>
```

Which will display:

```
original title!
new title!
new title!
```

Comment: I'm not including the pages at all. It's two completely separate pages. However each page has the same variable just with a different value.

Comment: Hm. Something doesn't add up here; did you copy the entire relevant source into your question?

Comment: @codedude Are you executing the files one at a time? If so--based on the information you've given--what you're describing is not possible. Are they perhaps _both_ included on a common third page? :]

Comment: I figured what I was doing wrong. I have an included php file that I thought wasn't doing anything when in fact it was defining the variable.